# Trying to interpret a VMF file

Tags: plane, interpretation, vectormath

I read a question about a similar topic on stackoverflow and I have part of the solution to my problem, let me explain what the problem is;
I need to know each and every block's position, and on the question that I read the questioner mentioned that the 3 vectors for "plane" are the determinants of the position, but I read the 1 answer that was there, and also checked the webpage the questioner provided and I couldn't understand it fully, could anyone please simplify it for me, this is holding me back from parsing VMF files.

Comment: Sorry for the messy question, for some reason SOF doesn't let me type in paragraphs.

Comment: The interpretation of the files is totally different than the parsing of the files. It seems your real question is "how does one interpret the plane types?". This really doesn't have much to do with Lua or parsing and you would have better luck getting answer if you tagged it with the proper tags. The explanation of planes from VMF files is located at https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/VMF_documentation:_World_Class#Planes. Also, I would add a reference to the SO question you mentioned.

Comment: Also, you add paragraphs to questions and answers by adding a newline between your paragraphs. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more help.

Comment: @ktb thanks. Already changed the tags, title and added a line break.